# Is a class the best way to hold this data C++?

Tags: c++, python, types

I have a list of US States along with various properties, and within those cities with various properties and this all needs to be created dynamically on startup, currently from a text file.

In python, with slightly broken syntax for readability, I would use a dict matrix (that sounds terrible) which could be represented something like this:

```
locations = {
    "Alabama": {
        "url" : "www.domain.com/page.php",
        "users": 8
        "cities" : {
            "city1": {
                "url" : "www.domain.com/page.php",
                "users": 2
            }
            "city2": {
                "url" : "www.domain.com/page.php",
                "users": 1
             }
        }
    }
}
```

I could use a class of course, but it's really not necessary just to represent it; in python for such a small list a dict would be much more useful and I currently have no plans to need the extra functionality of classes or a db. There will be a bit more details, and of course all of the states, and maybe 0-10 cities/regions per state, but relatively small all in all.

In C++ I could achieve a similar thing with nested unordered_map's perhaps, but for one thing I can't mix data types with an unordered map, so "users" would have to be a string instead of an int (and I'm unaware of a more suitable built in type), but I can easily make do by using strings for most things, however what made me come and ask this question is when creating the header declaration I quickly realized that it looked really ugly and hardly readable. It's going to be a const when it's created as well fwiw or else I'd just create it on the fly as with python. Even though I don't always follow them, I'm mostly looking for best practice advice here, how *should* I represent this data if I were getting a grade on it or otherwise publishing it?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming a `State` always has the same fields (`url`, `users` and `cities`), it's good practice to create a class for it.  Likewise with `City`.  Then you will end up with either:

- `map<string, State>` for your locations, and a `map<string, City>` for the cities in each state, or...
- `set<State>` for your locations (where `State` has a `name` field by which it's indexed) and a `set<City>` for the cities in each state (again, each with a `name` field).

You want to get into the habit of letting the type system work for you, as much as possible.

Comment: One note regarding `set`: they have the unfortunate property of preventing changes on the contained objects. For properties it might not be an issue (assuming those properties do not change), but for the number of users, for example, it might be annoying.

Comment: one more about std::set is that it stores only unique elements, this would be an issue if a state contains two cities with the same name and class City uses its name as index.

Answer (score 0):

why not store it in JSON or XML and get a JSON or XML reader library?

Comment: besides that installing extra libraries sucks sometimes

Comment: store it however you want, JSON seems fine, but the original question isn't about parsing the file, it's about how to represent the data with objects.

Comment: how to store it was part of the question, since he commented on the ugliness of the representation.

Answer (score 0):

In short: yes. You want a classes for your cities and states.

You may want to do something like have each state and city assigned a unique ID.
That id could be an index into an array for fast lookup.

You could then easily have each city keep track of what state it is a member of through the ID.

That should be a good starting point on how to organize it, since you really just asked a yes/no question.
The rest is left as an exercise for the reader. 
(it's really quite rare that one gets to legitimately say that in an answer)